# Unable to pass the React hooks state to Express server

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, react-hooks

In my react hooks web app the current state variable `nomRegister` returns an array (as below). I would like to pass this nomRegister to my server via Axios post request, so that I can parse the JSON and push values and save to database. Somehow I am not getting the value in server side? Getting undefined ! Could someone please advise what is the issue here ?

Provided a codesandbox link for what I have tried so far.

```
[{"name":"Rads","email":"rad@test1.com","reason":"Hello"},{"name":"Sam","email":"sam@y.com","reason":"Great"}]
```

Codesandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-dream-n1sfn?file=/src/App.js

`nominatePerson.js`

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Axios from "axios";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Multiselect from "multiselect-react-dropdown";

const options = [
  { id: 1, name: "Ath", email: "ath.best@test1.com", access: null },
  { id: 2, name: "Arnolds", email: "arnold@test1.com", access: null },
  { id: 3, name: "Alter", email: "alloop@test1.com", access: null },
  { id: 4, name: "Brandan", email: "brandan@test1.com", access: null },
  { id: 5, name: "Ron", email: "ron@test1.com", access: null },
  { id: 6, name: "Rads", email: "rad@test1.com", access: null },
  { id: 7, name: "Sam", email: "sam@y.com", access: null }
];
const NominatePerson = () => {
  const [option, setOption] = useState([]);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState([]);
  const [nomRegister, setNomRegister] = useState([{}]);
  const [helperText, setHelperText] = useState("");
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState("");
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
    reset
  } = useForm();
  const maxOptions = 3;
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    const userEmail = localStorage.getItem("loginEmail");
    setUserEmail(userEmail);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await Axios.get(
          "http://localhost:8000/service/nomineeslist"
        );
        //const data1 = res.data;
        setOption(options);
        console.log("Get the list of nominees :" + JSON.stringify(res.data));
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleTypeSelect = (e, i) => {
    const copy = [...selectedOption];
    copy.push(e[i]);
    setSelectedOption(copy);
  };

  const sendNomination = () => {
    console.log("What the Array holds: " + JSON.stringify(nomRegister));
    const fetchData = async (nomRegister) => {
      try {
        const res = await Axios.post(
          "http://localhost:8000/service/nominateperson",
          { userEmail },
          nomRegister
        );
        if (res.data) {
          console.log("Print data:" + res.data);
          const successMessage = res.data.message;
          setHelperText(successMessage);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  };

  options.forEach((option) => {
    option.displayValue = option.name + "\t" + option.email;
  });

  const handleChange = (e, i) => {
    const { name, email, value } = e.target;

    // immutating state (best practice)
    const updateList = nomRegister.map((item) => {
      return { ...item };
    });

    const select_Email = selectedOption.map((item) => {
      return item.email;
    });

    //change the specific array case depends on the id 
    updateList[i] = {
      ...updateList[i],
      name: name,
      email: select_Email[i],
      reason: value
    };
    setNomRegister(updateList);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Nominate a person</h1>
      <div className="nomineeSelectBox">
        <div id="dialog2" className="triangle_down1" />
        <div className="arrowdown">
          <Multiselect
            onSelect={(e) => handleTypeSelect(e, selectedOption.length)}
            options={selectedOption.length + 1 === maxOptions ? [] : options}
            displayValue="displayValue"
            showCheckbox={true}
            emptyRecordMsg={"Maximum nominees selected !"}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="nominationcount"></div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(sendNomination)}>
        <div className="nomineesSelectedList">
          <h4>Selected Nominees</h4>
          {selectedOption.map((x, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
              <div className="row eachrecord">
                <div className="column">
                  <label className="nomlabel">
                    {x?.name} <b>>></b>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <input
                  required
                  type="textarea"
                  placeholder="Please provide reason for nomination.."
                  key={i}
                  id={i}
                  name={x?.name}
                  className="nomineechoosed"
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}

          <div className="row">
            <div className="buttongroup">
              <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
              <input id="Cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NominatePerson;
```

[image]

Comment: Your `fetchData` function inside `sendNomination` makes a call to `Axios.post` with the third argument being `nomRegister`. `nomRegister` has been declared as an argument of `fetchData`. When you call `fetchData` you don't pass in an argument. As a result `nomRegister` will be `undefined`.

Comment: I have tried passed the ``nomRegister`` as fetchData(nomRegister); but still no data yet..I have added a break point for server side screen shot

Comment: Also the interface for `Axios.post` is `axios#post(url[, data[, config]])`. You seem to be passing `nomRegister` as the third argument which is for configuring the request.

Comment: @Wing Thank you very much , now getting the result..

Comment: No worries. FYI I'm voting to close this question as "caused by a typo", so while on topic it's not likely to be useful to future readers.

Comment: Hope you don't mind me sharing some learning points too: 1) If you don't already use a [linter](https://eslint.org/), try it out. If "[no shadow variables](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow)" was configured it would point out `nomRegister` being shadowed and as a result you would start checking the scope and usage of each variable and probably find the problem yourself. 2) If you don't already use type checking (either [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) or [Flow](https://flow.org/)), try it out too. It would've told you `Axios.post` was being used incorrectly.